# Unable to properly mount the /home PARTITION under /home DIRECTORY

Tags: kubuntu

I recently did a **Kubuntu-20.04 x64 LTS,** clean install on my **Dell-Vostro-3568,** i3-6006U, 4GB-RAM. During the installation process, I selected my previous Home partition (from Kubntu-18.04LTS) to be used as the new Home partition and selected **"/home"** as the mount point *(during installation)*.

So far so good, everything seems to work fine and the home partition is correctly mounted on the **"/home"** directory. However there is one problem. During installation the system creted a home for my **"/home/mohit"**. And thus, now the linux home parition also has one more partition for my username and it is currently showing in the **/home/mohit**.

So the problem is that I have got two **homes** now. The one that is created by the installation process and the one that I selected to be mounted under **/home**.

I tried to fix this problem by editing the **/etc/fstab** file and instead of mounting **home partition** under **/home** I selected it to be mounted under **/home/mohit** but that is causing the system to freeze on the login prompt. And I had to drop to the root shell to undo my changes.

Also while doing all this my system now starts to give this additional error *some pcie severity corrected error, something like that*, however it is not a big problem I will tackle it myself.

The main problem is how to correctly mount the previous partition so that my system has only one home for my username "mohit".

**NOTE:** *My linux knowlege is Intermediate, so any instructions you tell, I guess I can manage to follow along.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also if I try to completely comment out the entry for /home partition in the fstab file then the system freezes again on the login prompt.

Comment: Did the installation really create a *partition* `/home/mohit` - or did it create a new home *directory* for user `mohit` and place it in `/home`? What does `findmnt -T /home/mohit` say?

Comment: Does the old home partition that you want to use contain only a directory /mohit, or does it directly contain the home directory's contents, like /Pictures, /Documents etc.?